# Use a for loop to calculate and print the average of the third list items in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dictionary and am looking to calculate and print the average of all prices (3rd item in each list):

right now I have each list item recalled to find the value. This is simple to do for a short dictionary but I am hoping there is a shorter/simpler way to do this for when I have a larger set.

```
price = {
    1: ['Blueberry', 'US', 1.31],
    2: ['Pineapples', 'Brazil', 3.71],
    3: ['Pear', 'Costa Rica' , 0.58],
    4: ['Plum', 'US', 1.00],
    5: ['Grapes', 'US', 1.25],
    6: ['Papaya', 'Costa Rica', 0.4 ],
    7: ['Blueberry', 'Mexico' , 1.58],
    8: ['Plum', 'Mexico', 1.50],
    9: ['Grapes', 'Italy', 2.25],
    10: ['Blueberry', 'Italy', 2.50 ]
}
```

I am trying to find the average of just the prices and separate them from the other values associated with each key but so far am unable to do so.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what you have done so far, provide your code in your answer to get better help from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
price = {
    1: ['Blueberry', 'US', 1.31],
    2: ['Pineapples', 'Brazil', 3.71],
    3: ['Pear', 'Costa Rica' , 0.58],
    4: ['Plum', 'US', 1.00],
    5: ['Grapes', 'US', 1.25],
    6: ['Papaya', 'Costa Rica', 0.4 ],
    7: ['Blueberry', 'Mexico' , 1.58],
    8: ['Plum', 'Mexico', 1.50],
    9: ['Grapes', 'Italy', 2.25],
    10: ['Blueberry', 'Italy', 2.50 ]
}

total = 0
for value in price.values():
    total += value[2]
print("Average: {}".format(total/len(price.values())))
```

Output:

```
Average: 1.6079999999999999
```

It is fast enough as you are only iterating through the values just once and the code should do fine even for a large dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

### Using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org):

- The data will now be in a form for easy analysis

  - get the mean
  - get the mean by country or product
- `pandas` is the tool to use, if you really want to gather insight from your data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(price, orient='index')
df.columns = ['product', 'country', 'price']

    product     country  price
  Blueberry          US   1.31
 Pineapples      Brazil   3.71
       Pear  Costa Rica   0.58
       Plum          US   1.00
     Grapes          US   1.25
     Papaya  Costa Rica   0.40
  Blueberry      Mexico   1.58
       Plum      Mexico   1.50
     Grapes       Italy   2.25
  Blueberry       Italy   2.50

print(df.price.mean())

>>> 1.6079999999999999

print(df.groupby('country')['price'].mean())

country
Brazil        3.710000
Costa Rica    0.490000
Italy         2.375000
Mexico        1.540000
US            1.186667
Name: price, dtype: float64

df.groupby('country')['price'].mean().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
df.groupby(['product'])['price'].mean().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
item_mean = df.groupby(['product'])['price'].mean().reset_index()

plt.bar(x='product', height='price', data=item_mean)
plt.hlines(product_avg, xmin='Blueberry', xmax='Plum', label='mean', linestyles='dotted')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `mean()` method.

```py
from statistics import mean

price = {
    1: ['Blueberry', 'US', 1.31],
    2: ['Pineapples', 'Brazil', 3.71],
    3: ['Pear', 'Costa Rica' , 0.58],
    4: ['Plum', 'US', 1.00],
    5: ['Grapes', 'US', 1.25],
    6: ['Papaya', 'Costa Rica', 0.4 ],
    7: ['Blueberry', 'Mexico' , 1.58],
    8: ['Plum', 'Mexico', 1.50],
    9: ['Grapes', 'Italy', 2.25],
    10: ['Blueberry', 'Italy', 2.50 ]
}

mean(map(lambda x: x[2],price.values()))
```